# Trouble with UNION SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been working days to solve this little problem.

I am trying to get data from two tables by using UNION. But the return are this error code:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in.....

What does that mean and what am I doing wrong?

My code line looks like this:

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablet1 WHERE id1=$cho1 UNION SELECT * FROM $tablet2 WHERE id2=21");

Answer (score 1):

Your query is failing and returning `FALSE` instead of producing a query resource. That's why `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an error.

Always check the returning value. You can do it like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
if ($result) {
    //Iterate through the resultset
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ...
    }
} else {
    echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error();
    //Do whatever you need to do to recover

}
```

**As others suggested check and make sure that both select statements in `UNION` return the same number of columns and columns in corresponding positions have the same data type.**

> **See more [13.2.8.4. UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)**
>
> Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT
> statement should have the same data type. (For example, the first
> column selected by the first statement should have the same type as
> the first column selected by the other statements.)

*As a side note:* Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Here is good [PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). And your code is wide open to sql-injections. Once again use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure both tables column are same  in terms of their data types and column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT T1.column1,T1.column2,T1.column3,T1.column4,T1.column5 
                       FROM $tablet1 T1 WHERE T1.id1=$cho1 

                       UNION 

                       SELECT T2.column1,T2.column2,T2.column3,T2.column4,T2.column5 
                       FROM $tablet2 T2 WHERE T2.id2=21 
                      ");
```

The Number of Columns in Table 1 and its Data Type in Table 1 should match Table2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check no of column and data type should me same in both the query because u are using UNION operator.

Now if you want to use mysql_fetch_array:

The mysql_fetch_array function takes a MySQL query resource as an argument ($result) and returns the first row of data returned by the mysql_query.

Like the code bewlo:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```